# Question - How to add window resize listener to document ready jquery function?

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery script that opens sub menus but I need it to function differently at different window sizes.

I one main menu that I use for both on-canvas and off-canvas by using media queries. The problem is that my script to open the sub-menus works correctly when the site loads but if you resize the window above or below 768px, which is the break point for switching between the on-canvas and off-canvas menu, the script doesn't respond accordingly. Instead, it continues to function at the original window size.

How do I add a window resize listener so that the script fires correctly after the window is resized above or below the 768px break point.

Thank you for any help you can provide. I truly do appreciate it.

Here is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches)
  {
    $('.toggle-sub').click(function() {
      $(this).children('.menu-sub').slideToggle(200);
      $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-chevron-up');
    });
  } else {
    $('.toggle-sub').hover(function() {
      $(this).children('.menu-sub').slideToggle(200);
      $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-chevron-up');
      $(this).siblings().find('.menu-sub').slideUp(200);
      $(this).siblings().find('i').removeClass('fa-chevron-up');

      $('html').click(function(e) {
        if (e.target != '.menu-sub' && $(e.target).parents('.menu-main').length == 0) {
          $('.menu-sub').slideUp(200);
          $('.menu-main').find('i').removeClass('fa-chevron-up');
        };
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you add your html too?

Comment: I have a codepen in my comments below that show the original script with the html and css I'm using.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I want the submenus to expand onclick when below or equal to 767px and to expand on hover when above or equal to 768px. This way the offcanvas menu is onliclick and the oncanvas menu is onhover.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a [resize()](https://api.jquery.com/resize/) function. What you need to do is wrapping your functions inside this function.

```
$(window).on('resize', function(e){
    YOUR FUNCTION GOES IN HERE

})
```

Using `window.innerWith` to check current window width.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But it doesn't work correctly, for some reason. It works on load, but when I resize the window past the 768px break point, it causes the sub-menus to scroll up and down repeated. How do I stop that? Thanks, again.

Comment: can you provide the HTML markup, please?  Or you can set up a quick code demo under your question. It's easier for other people to debug.

Comment: I'm getting a different result in codepen than I am on my test box. Not sure why, but here is the codepen for the original: https://codepen.io/jamillard/pen/YdJEZB and the new codepen https://codepen.io/jamillard/pen/jXeaKB.

Comment: When screen size is below 768, your submenus are just sliding up and down, is this your issue? Since you didn't mention what the issue looks like in your question.

Comment: If you start at above the 768px break point, the oncanvas menu works correctly but on resizing below 768px then the offcanvas submens scroll up and down repeated. If you start below 768px, the offcanvas works correctly but after resizing above 768px, the oncanvas submens scroll up and down repeated. That's the result I'm getting on my local box but code pen is functioning a little different, but still not correct. Thanks again.

Comment: Also, I think you using JS to do hover effect is an overkill. Try to do that with CSS `:hover`. It's quite simple.

Comment: I originally had :hover in css. but it applied universally regardless of the jquery script to make it "onclick" at below 768px window size. So I thought I would try using js or jquery to control the hover and also apply an onclick at below 768px. All I want is for the submenus to function onclick when below or equal to  767px and on hover when above or equal to 786px. And with the siblings condition for above or equal to 768px.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function adjustMenu(){
  if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches)
  {
    $('.toggle-sub').click(function() {
    $(this).children('.menu-sub').slideToggle(200);
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-chevron-up');
  });
  } else {
    $('.toggle-sub').hover(function() {
    $(this).children('.menu-sub').slideToggle(200);
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-chevron-up');
    $(this).siblings().find('.menu-sub').slideUp(200);
    $(this).siblings().find('i').removeClass('fa-chevron-up');
    $('html').click(function(e) {
    if (e.target != '.menu-sub' && $(e.target).parents('.menu-main').length == 0) {
      $('.menu-sub').slideUp(200);
      $('.menu-main').find('i').removeClass('fa-chevron-up');
    };
   });
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
      adjustMenu();
     $(window).on('resize',function(){
           adjustMenu();
     });
});
```

Note : just used your own code inside adjustMenu(),

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried that, using menuSub() as the funciton, and for some reason, it doesn't work, and it breaks all my other jquery scripts. I copied and pasted your code and got the same result. I'm not sure why because my first thought was this solution... I haven't figured out why it breaks everything, but in my comments to Speir (above), there is a codepen for my original code.

Comment: can you create a replica on jsfiddle ? with the html,css and script. i can take a look